# DI object method

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, silex

How do I inject dependency in some of the object methods instead of the constructor?

The example below works fine for __constructor injection

How do I inject the DateTime object in indexAction?

app.php

```
 $app['index.controller'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
       return new Controllers\IndexController(new \DateTime());
     });
```

IndexController.php

```
namespace Moo\Controllers;

class IndexController
{
  private $date;
  public function __construct(\DateTime $date)
  {
    $this->date = $date;
  }
  public function indexAction()
  {
   return $this->date->format('y-m-d');
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the propblem you have with inject it in constructor ?

Comment: What if I have let's say 5 methods and each of them require a different object to deal with. Isn't reasonable to inject each  only in the method that depends of instead in the constructor?

Comment: then what about having all objects in an array ? or a service you can call for the specific object ? Well php`s class-object is designed to have a constructor to set properties before running "actions" and "dependencyInjection" is that, and as all your actions are part of this class you may also think about having different controllers for the different objects, i guess a service with a "generic object-getter" is the bet solution

Comment: You're looking for method injection. It is in Laravel 5 http://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-method-injection. Threre you can find inspiration, since it's built on Symfony components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class has different dependencies depending on which method is called, than these methods should probably be defined in separate classes.

In case of controllers I think the rules are simple. Dependencies your action methods need should be passed via the constructor. Anything coming with a request should come as a method argument.

I'm not sure what kind of dependencies you're trying to inject. **If they're just services, than you should split your controller to multiple classes.** Big number of constructor arguments is a code smell. It's good you're concerned by it, but you're trying to solve it in a wrong way.

If the dependency is coming with a request, you should inject it into your controller method (action). **A controller method should accept a request and return a response.**

All route placeholders are automatically registered as a Request attribute. So if your date comes from a request:

```
$app->get('/my/path/{date}', 'index.controller:indexAction');
```

It will be available as a request attribute:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $request->attributes->get('date');
}
```

Any request attributes can be directly injected into the controller:

```
public function indexAction($date)
{
}
```

This also means, that if you manually set a request attribute, it will be possible to inject it to your controller. It's matched by name:

```
// somewhere in your code (event perhaps)
$request->attributes->set('myDate', new \DateTime());

// in your controller
public function indexAction(\DateTime $myDate)
{
}
```

Finally you can convert simple types coming with the request, to more complex ones with [route variable converters](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#route-variables-converters).

```
$callback = function ($post, Request $request) {
    return new Post($request->attributes->get('slug'));
};

$app->get('/blog/{id}/{slug}', 'your.controller:indexAction')
    ->convert('post', $callback);
```

Read the docs for more.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, as you won't probably want to do this, its is, indeed, possible to do method injection in Silex (in fact it is the Pimple container the one responsible to do it) by using the *extend* method:

```
<?php

$app['some_service'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
  return SomeClass($app['some_dependency']);
});

$app['some_service'] = $app->extend('some_service', function($instance, $app) {
   $instance->setSomeDependency($app['another_dependency']);

   return $instance;
});
```

Having said that you should take into account what @JakubZalas is explaining as you will not want to call your controller action inside the *extend* method (you want to be called by the dispatcher).

Comment: It's gonna inject deps every time, no?

Comment: AFAIK it does not as the service is shared so it won't create a new instance every time you want to retrieve it from the container thus it won't call the extend method every time, only at the creation of the service, but I could be entirely wrong :-) I'm not at my dev computer so I cannot test it right now, worth remembering and trying back at home

Comment: What I mean is it will inject ALL deps every time the service is initialzed. It is initialized once, but all services are injected, even those which are not necessarily gonna be used. This is not something we can solve with container, responsibilities need to be segregated.

Comment: Definitively true, it will inject the dependencies even though they may be not needed, and I completely agree with this "*This is not something we can solve with container, responsibilities need to be segregated*". I just wanted to show that method injection is possible, but as you pointed out may be not the route to go